# Prestashop - HelperForm - Radio is not checked in BO

Tags: php, prestashop, helper, prestashop-1.5, form-helpers

I'm blocked on my prestashop website and I need your help.

**So here it is** :
I need a radio button on my prestashop BO on my categorie page. I'm developing a module in order to display specific categories on my Index page. So, with the Helper form I've added a radio button with 2 values (1 for active, and 0 for inactive). And here is my problem. The value is well saved in my database, but when I come back in the Back office categorie page, none of my radios are checked !

**My Prestashop version : Prestashop 1.5.6.2**

Do you have any idea ?

Here is my code so far in the AdminCategoriesController.php :

```
array(
                'type' => 'radio',
                'label' => $this->l('Categorie à afficher sur l\'accueil ? :'),
                'name' => 'featured_category',
                'required' => false,
                'class' => 't',
                'is_bool' => true,
                'values' => array(
                    array(
                        'id' => 'featured_category_on',
                        'value' => 1,
                    ),
                    array(
                        'id' => 'featured_category_off',
                        'value' => 0,
                    )
                )
            ),
```

And this is what I've added in category.php

```
'featured_category' =>      array('type' => self::TYPE_INT, 'validate' => 'isBool', 'validate' => 'isUnsignedId')
```

With also :

```
public $featured_category = 0;
```

Information :

- I've modified the /classes/category.php file and the
  AdminCategoriesController.php in order to add the field.

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found out where was my mistake, so I'm posting it if someone has the same trouble.

**Contrary to Text Area which are save in "PS_CATEGORY_LANG", radio and checkbox are saved in "PS_CATEGORY", so be sure to only save your field in the PS_CATEGORY table, otherwise prestashop won't be able to read the saved value.**

As always, the mistake was **** simple ! :)